# insert data to table in for loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop, mysqli

Here's my table

```
id | total  | adult | kid | babies
```

Here's my data to be inserted

`total = 3, adult = 2, kid = 1, babies = 0`

It should be inserted like

```
id | total  | adult | kid | babies
 1 |     3  |     1 |   0 |      0 
 2 |     3  |     1 |   0 |      0
 3 |     3  |     0 |   1 |      0
```

How can i insert my data like the above structure ?

I tried like

```
for ($i=0; $i <$total ; $i++) 
{ 
$query = "INSERT INTO trip(total, adult, kid, babies) 
VALUES (
    '".$total."',
    '".$adult."',
    '".$kid."',
    '".$babies."'
    )";
$mysqli->query($query);
}
```

It is always inserting the same data. But how can i insert the data like the one i given above ?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this schema is not quite right. What relates the records together? You're violating the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) here and need to apply proper [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) techniques. I'd advocate separating the "trip" from the "passengers", inserting a record into the trip first, then adding passenger records of the form `type="adult"` in another table. Then you can do things like `SELECT trip_id, type, SUM(number) GROUP BY trip_id,type` to get these counts.

Comment: As explained, I think that `$adult` and the other variables must be equal to `1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have three different loops, one for adults, one for kids and one for babies:

```
//Prepare the insert statement.
$mysqli->prepare = "INSERT INTO trip(total, adult, kid, babies) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

//Bind some variables.
$mysqli->bind_param('iiii', $total, $flagAdult, $flagKid, $flagBaby);

//Insert the adults.
$flagAdult = 1;
$flagKid = 0;
$flagBaby = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<$adult; $i++) 
{ 
    $mysqli->execute();
}

//Insert the kids.
$flagAdult = 0;
$flagKid = 1;
$flagBaby = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<$kid; $i++) 
{ 
    $mysqli->execute();
}

//Insert the babies.
$flagAdult = 0;
$flagKid = 0;
$flagBaby = 1;
for ($i=0; $i<$babies; $i++) 
{ 
    $mysqli->execute();
}
```

Your code was vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html), so I changed it to use `bind_param`, see documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

I asumed that the data is integers (since there are only 0 and 1), but if you in fact want to use strings for some reason you will need to change `'iiii'` (meaning four integers) to `'ssss'` (meaning four strings).

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection. I will update my answer to fix it.

Comment: A single prepared statement here could be used in each case with different bindings.

Comment: Valid point, @tadman. Thank you for your input. I have modified my answer in line with what you suggested. Please consider reversing any downvotes.